# Which band is which in an RGB image

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, rgb, orthophoto

I have several RGB images of which I made an orthomosaic image. I would like to create a VARI vegetation indice. QGIS shows 4 bands in the raster calculator. Which band is which of the RGB bands? One of them is probably an alpha channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually its in order - R, G, B, and then any fourth band is a transparency band (often referred to as A).

But without documentation or a file to look at, impossible to be certain. Check the documentation from the data supplier.